# Хочу добавить форму из однаго html шаблона в другой шаблон

Tags: html, python, django

Вот этот шаблон comment.html пытался разными способами тапа {% include %}

```
{% block comment %}

        {% for comment in form_list %}
            {{ comment.WhoAreYou }}
            {{ comment.textComment }}
        {% endfor %}

        <h4>Comments</h4>

    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

нужно добаавить вот сюда

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}


{% block content %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1 class=" text-info">{{articles.title}}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          <p> {{articles.post|safe|linebreaks}}  </p>
            <h3 align="right" class=" text-info"> Опубликованно: {{articles.date|date:"d-m-Y в H:i"}}</h3>
      </div>

        <h4>Comments</h4>

    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Уберите из первого шаблона тег `{% block %}` и `{% endblock %}`.
Добавьте его во второй шаблон с помощью `{% include %}`.